# Install Typing packages behind corporate proxy

Tags: typescript-typings

I'm getting the error message below. I searched for the self signed certificate problem and I got to [this](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/106) answer, but I did everything that is mentioned here. I'm just going around and still no success.

**What I did so far**:

- I have a .typingsrc in my %USERPROFILE% directory containing the example below
- I have another .typingsrc file in my project root containing the example below
- I have tried every combination of the example below

**Questions**:

- where the .typingsrc file should be placed in Windows 7?
- Where can I find a documentation about properties of .typingsrc file? It is always just mentioned and there is no example with parameters.
- Is .typingsrc a JSON file or something else?

Still no success.

Do you have a solution for this?

```
{
        "rejectUnauthoriozed":false,
        "httpProxy": "",
        "httpsProxy": "",
        "insecure":true,
        "strict-ssl":false
}
```

Error message:

```
C:\..\src\UI.Spa>typings install dt~angular --global --save
typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/angular/versions/latest"
typings ERR! caused by self signed certificate in certificate chain

typings ERR! cwd C:\..\src\UI.Spa
typings ERR! system Windows_NT 6.1.7601
typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\..\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.js" "install" "dt~angular" "--global" "--save"
typings ERR! node -v v5.10.1
typings ERR! typings -v 1.1.0
typings ERR! code EUNAVAILABLE

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My `.typingsrc` file is located at the project root level (where typings.json is located).

It simply contains:

```
proxy="http://xxx.xxx.xxx:80"
rejectUnauthorized=false
```

Comment: For an authenticating proxy I had to use `http://myuserid:mypassword@myproxy:8080/`

Comment: for me just the `rejectUnauthorized=false ` was enough

Answer (score 4):

If you're working at a corporate company that blocks/restricts commands such as npm install, you'll need to setup a proxy which allows you to bypass that. I'm assuming if you've gotten this far, you've already done that. Make sure you remember the proxy you used so that you can add it to the .typingsrc file in the next step.

Just create a .typingsrc file in the root of your project and paste the following:

proxy="http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080" (this is where you paste the proxy you used)
rejectUnauthorized=false

After doing this, you should be able to run your global typing commands without errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try "--proxy" option.

For example

```
C:\..\src\UI.Spa>typings --proxy "http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/" install dt~angular --global --save
```